# Trouble with metric in normal coordinates

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems

I'm having serious trouble understanding something which should be, allegedly, quite trivial. As explained in the following lecture notes

[https://people.math.harvard.edu/~shlomo/docs/semi_riemannian_geometry.pdf](https://people.math.harvard.edu/%7Eshlomo/docs/semi_riemannian_geometry.pdf)

on page 126-127 one can define normal coordinates on a neighborhood of a manifold M as follows:
$$
x^i=l^i\circ exp^{-1}
$$
where $l^i$ is the dual basis of the orthonormal basis $\{e_i\}$ in $T_pM$. The thing that I'm not able to understand is how to prove that the metric looks flat in $p$ with these coordinates. I know that the result is something like

$$
g_{\mu\nu}=\langle(\frac{\partial }{\partial x^{\mu}})_p,(\frac{\partial }{\partial x^{\nu}})_p\rangle=\langle\mathrm{d}(exp)_p\,e_\nu,\,\mathrm{d}(exp)_p\,e_\mu\rangle=\langle\,e_\mu,\,e_\nu\rangle=\delta_{\mu\nu}
$$
But I'm not able to do prove it. Any help is really appreciated.